# Assertion Error

Tags: truffle, ganache, truffle-test

Solidity file

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Todo {

  struct User {
    uint id;
    string name;
  }
  User[] public users;
  uint public nextId = 1;

  function create(string memory name) public {
    users.push(User(nextId, name));
    nextId++;
  }

  function read(uint id) view public returns(uint, string memory) {
    uint i = find(id);
    return(users[i].id, users[i].name);
  }

  function update(uint id, string memory name) public {
    uint i = find(id);
    users[i].name = name;
  }

  function destroy(uint id) public {
    uint i = find(id);
    delete users[i];
  }

  function find(uint id) view internal returns(uint) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      if(users[i].id == id) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    revert('User does not exist');
  }

}
```

test file

```
    const Todo = artifacts.require('Todo');

contract('Todo', () => {
  let todo = null;
  before(async() => {
    todo = await Todo.deployed();
  });

  it('Should create a new user', async () => {
    await todo.create('Kirean');
    const user = await todo.read(1);
    assert(user[0].toNumber() === 1);
    assert(user[1] === 'Kirean');
  });

  it('Should update a user', async () => {
    await todo.update(1, 'Kireannn');
    const user = await todo.read(1);
    assert(user[0].toNumber() === 1);
    assert(user[1] === 'Kireannn');
  });

  it('Should not update a non-existing user', async () =>
  {
    try{
    await todo.update(2, 'Kireannn');
  } catch(e) {
  assert(e.message.includes('user does not exist'));

    return;

  }
  assert(false);
});

it('Should delete a user', async () => {
  await todo.destroy(1);
  try{
    await todo.read(1);
  } catch(e) {
  assert(e.message.includes('user does not exist'));

    return;
  }
  assert(false);
  });

  it('Should not delete a non-existing user', async () => {
    try {
      await todo.destroy(10);
    } catch (e) {
    assert(e.message.includes('user does not exist'));

      return;
  }
  assert(false);
});

});
```

[image: terminal]

Answer (score 0):

The array elements start at row `0`. This looks suspicious.

```
 uint public nextId = 1;
```

Pursuing that a little farther ...

```
  it('Should create a new user', async () => {
    await todo.create('Kirean');
    const user = await todo.read(1);
```

You pushed `Kirean` into row 0 and then tried to access row 1 which is out of range, so the contract reverted.

Hope it helps.